# HTML Zoom on Mouse

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a pixel art website where users can draw on an HTML canvas like r/place. I have a working zoom using the mouse wheel, but the zoom always centers around the middle of the canvas. Instead, I want the zoom to zoom based on my mouse pointer position, so that the canvas zooms in/out relative to the mouse cursor.

Currently, the JavaScript code for my zooming looks like this:

```js
// Add variables for zoom and pan
let zoomLevel = 1;
let panX = 0;
let panY = 0;

// Function to update the canvas size and redraw pixels when zooming
function updateCanvasAndRedraw() {
  canvas.width = WIDTH * zoomLevel;
  canvas.height = HEIGHT * zoomLevel;
  updateCanvasContextProperties(); // Update canvas context properties for zooming
  drawPixelsWithZoom();
}


// Event listener for mouse wheel to handle zooming
canvas.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  const zoomFactor = e.deltaY > 0 ? 0.9 : 1.1; // Adjust zoom speed as per your preference
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const mouseX = (e.clientX - rect.left) / zoomLevel;
  const mouseY = (e.clientY - rect.top) / zoomLevel;
  zoomLevel *= zoomFactor;
  zoomLevel = clampZoom(zoomLevel); // Ensure zoom stays within MIN_ZOOM and MAX_ZOOM
  updateCanvasAndRedraw();
  updateCanvasContextProperties(); // Call this function after updating the zoom level
  e.preventDefault();
  drawCenterPixelSelection(centerX, centerY);
  updateCenterCoordinates();
});
```

other code:

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white; /* Set the canvas background color to white */
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

Would be awesome if someone could guide me on how to modify the code so that the zoom is centered around the mouse cursor position instead of the center of the canvas. I want the canvas to zoom in/out relative to where the mouse cursor is placed.

Thank you for your help!